# MySql subselect havning where clause with value from main select

Tags: mysql

there's select which i'm trying to make work

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.client_key, client_name 
FROM Bloggers AS a 
LEFT JOIN BloggersPosts AS b 
ON a.client_key = b.client_key 
WHERE a.status = 1 AND 
0 NOT IN (SELECT MIN(STATUS) FROM BloggersPosts AS c WHERE c.client_key=a.client_key)
```

For some reason `0 NOT IN (SELECT MIN(STATUS) FROM BloggersPosts AS c WHERE c.client_key=a.client_key)` is not working, any ideas how to make it work?

EDIT: by not working i mean that if i delete the susbelect - my query gives result rows. But as soon as I add it - there is empty result. At the same time when i execute the subselect alone `SELECT MIN(STATUS) FROM BloggersPosts` - it returns 1, which means that putting it as subselect - should return results too, but it doesn't.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Error? or not expected record? What is your sample data and expected result

Comment: sorry, edited my initial post

Comment: You're saying that the subselect returns 1.  0 != 1, so that's why the outer query is returning no records. 0 is not in [1].

Comment: Susbselect returns 1, so i was assuming that i will get all the records which do not have 0 in subselect. So if I have 1 then 0 is not 1 and I should get the result? no?

Comment: And actually no matter what i put there 0 NOT IN or 0 IN or 1 IN... there are no results as soon as the subquery is added

Comment: You query doesn't make sense? what do you want, your joining with blogpost and again in the where clause ur matching with min(status)

Comment: Bloggers has many BloggersPosts, so with the last subquery I wanted to add a where clause that would select all the bloggers who do not have ANY of their blogposts with status=0. Ideally I would use MIN(b.status)>0, however that brings the error: Invalid use of group function since there is no group by

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will do your job. Trying different solution for your problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.client_key, client_name 
FROM Bloggers AS a 
JOIN (SELECT client_key, MIN(STATUS) minstatus FROM BloggersPosts GROUP BY client_key) b
ON a.client_key = b.client_key AND minstatus <> 0
WHERE a.status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN instead, something like similar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.client_key, client_name, MIN(c.STATUS) blog_status
FROM Bloggers AS a 
LEFT JOIN BloggersPosts AS b ON a.client_key = b.client_key 
LEFT JOIN BloggersPosts AS c ON c.client_key = a.client_key
WHERE a.status = 1 
HAVING blog_status <> 0
```